# Sharing an arraylist by Email in apps

Tags: android

I am very new in android; I am working on an application, where I need to send a mail of list (array list) items by using Share option. Currently, I am able to send the list in array format like [htc, motorla, samsung] by using the below code:

```
private void shareIt(){
    //String[] mailBody = (String[])cl.toString()
    int array_size = cl.getCount();
    String[] mailBody = new String[array_size];
    for (int i =0;i<array_size;i++){
        mailBody[i] = cl.getItem(i).toString();
    }

    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Arrays.toString(mailBody));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
}
```

But I want to create a mail body in table format like:
htc
motorla
samsung

Please help me out to format the array in table format; which will be applicable for `sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Arrays.toString(mailBody));`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the receiver understands HTML you could add a `<br/>` at the end of each word to indicate a newline. If you control the receiver you could use any character (or even use the format you have now) to indicate the newline and parse accordingly.

Send with `<br/>` would look like

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 0;i < array_size; i++){
    sb.append(cl.getItem(i).toString()).append("<br/>")
}

//...
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sb.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks! but gmail or any mail is not accepting this format <br/>

Comment: Thanks lxx, it worked by using html concept : private void shareIt(){
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  int array_size = cl.getCount();
  for (int i =0;i<array_size;i++){
   sb.append(cl.getItem(i).toString()).append("<br/>");
  }
  
  Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  sharingIntent.setType("text/html");
  sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Shopping List");
  sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(sb.toString()));
  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
  
 }